# Regular Expression help or an alternative

Tags: java

I have a file that looks like the following with lines of tags. I have:

```
Pattern.compile("<(?:TIMEX TYPE|ENAMEX TYPE)=.+?>(.+?)</(?:TIMEX|ENAMEX)>");
```

This gets the data I need if both tags are on one line. My problem is dealing with the following lines:

```
<ENAMEX
TYPE="CITED">1</ENAMEX>
```

If there is a split in the middle of the tag it does not work correctly. So I am looking for help improving my regular expression, or an alternative that works with non standard xml tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) switch, *and* a match for whitespace (`"\\s+"`), rather than a literal space:

```
Pattern.compile("<(?:TIMEX\\s+TYPE|ENAMEX\\s+TYPE)=.+?>(.+?)</(?:TIMEX|ENAMEX)>", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

This excerpt from the javadoc for this switch explains the `DOTALL` switch:

> In dotall mode, the expression . matches any character, including a line terminator.

Also note that despite its name, the [`Pattern.MULTILINE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) switch *won't* help you here.

Comment: But it's not the `.` that he's having an issue with. He has a line return where his regex is expecting a space.

Comment: I have tried that and it does not solve the problem. It does not do anything, the new line is giving me all sorts of problems. Yes the new line instead of the space, I can not figure out how to resolve.

Comment: @JamesMontagne You're right (although he still needs the switch!) Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for ' ' (a single space), why not look for any whitespace, any number of times? Should be something like '\s+'.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving you an alternative by example.  A search replace before your pattern matching could help you.

```
    final static String NEWLINE = "\n";
    final static String SPACE = " ";

public static void main(String[] args) {

            String s = "<ENAMEX\n TYPE=\"CITED\">1</ENAMEX>";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(?:TIMEX TYPE|ENAMEX TYPE)=.+?>(.+?)</(?:TIMEX|ENAMEX)>");

            s = s.replaceAll(NEWLINE, SPACE);

            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Start index: " + matcher.start());
        System.out.println("End index: " + matcher.end());
    }
}
```